# How to display content properly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to display all of the objects that are fetched from my api, but the content is not being rendered at all.

When I try to `console.log(contact)` I get the correct response, but it is not being displayed. 
`console.log(contact)`:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{_id: "59c7b975d9d7eed098507a64", contactTitle: "Mrs", …}
1:{_id: "59c86766b3434b06533f3374", contactTitle: "Mr", …}
length:2
```

And my component:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchContacts } from '../../actions';

class ContactList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchContacts();
    }
    renderContacts() {
        return _.map(this.props.contacts, contact => {
            console.log(contact);
            return (
                <div className="collection" key={contact._id}>
                    <Link to="/" className="collection-item">
                        {contact.contactName}
                    </Link>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Contacts</h3>
                <div>{this.renderContacts()}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ contacts }) {
    return { contacts };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchContacts })(ContactList);
```

I also have a `contact.reducer.js`:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CONTACTS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And `actions.js`:

```
export const fetchContacts = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/contacts');

    dispatch({type: FETCH_CONTACTS, payload: res.data })
}
```

I don't understand why it is not being displayed, I did the same thing in a similar project and it was working.

Comment: Inside the `map` function you console.log the result. What do you get back? A single contact or the array?

Comment: @HemersonCarlin I get an array of all the contacts, I copied the reply in my question above (first code snippet)

Comment: So this is your error. If I understood it, you are mapping an array and each item also happens to be an array. Right?

Comment: You should look at what's being delivered by `/api/contacts` because you're assigning `res.data` to your app state but it looks like `res.data` contains an array called `contacts` which contains _another_ array that _actually_ holds your contact data.

Comment: Are you sure you want to map from your component? Let's say your api changes for some reason in the future? I'd flatten this array before dispatching the action to the reducer.

Comment: Ooh I see @Andy, I changed res.data.contacts and now I get all the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments (by me and @Andy_D), your api response seems to be sending your data different than you are expecting. Either you can change that on back-end side or:

```
export const fetchContacts = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get('/api/contacts');

  dispatch({type: FETCH_CONTACTS, payload: res.data.contacts })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is in your reducer/the format of the API response - what you're ending up with in your store is something like this:

```
{
  contacts: [
    [{}, {}]
  ]
}
```

Check the format of the data in the API response, and make sure you modify it before storing it so that it's a flat array, which is what your component is expecting.

If you're not, I would highly recommend using the React dev-tools and redux dev-tools here as you'll easily be able to see the current props of your components and state of your store.